# Iterate a feature by expression with unique values in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, iteration, select-by-expression

Im trying to automate the process of select by expression and afterwards export it to a new layer in Qgis using Python. The Layer I'm using is called "Brutvoegel" and my goal is to get all the unique Values of the feature "Art", select each unique value and store them in a new layer with the name of the value.

Here is what I got so far:

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Brutvoegel')
layer = layers[0]

myfilepath = iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
(p, nameFile) = os.path.split(myfilepath)

uniquevalues = [];
uniqueprovider = layer.dataProvider()
fields = uniqueprovider.fields()
id = fields.indexFromName('Art')
uniquevalues = uniqueprovider.uniqueValues( id )

for i in uniquevalues:
    layer.selectByExpression("\"Art\"='i'")
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, f"{p}/{i}.shp",'utf-8', driverName = 'ESRI Shapefile', onlySelected=True)
```

I first active the layer, get my path where it's stored and then a list of the unique values from "Art". In the last step I want to take this list and go through each value, select and export it. If I run the script I get all the new shapfiles with the name of the value but no attribute tabel in it or any spatial refrence. When I select may layer with:

```py
layer.selectByExpression("\"Art\"='Swk'") #Swk is an example of a value
```

and then write it with the QgsVectorFileWriter it works. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: You can use the Split Vector Layer algorithm. From Python you can call it in this way: `processing.run("native:splitvectorlayer", {'INPUT': layer, 'FIELD':'Art','FILE_TYPE':0,'OUTPUT':'/tmp/outputs/'})` Where FILE_TYPE:0 is GeoPackage.

Comment: Thanks that did the job!